# Lubuntu gtar not responding

Tags: command-line, software-installation, lubuntu, tar, lxterminal

I am using Lubuntu32 bit. ubuntu 15.10, linux4.2.0 32 bit in VM ware.
I am trying to install prismtech DDS community edition for a cross compiler.
In the instructions I was asked to use gtar .........
but I came across the following error for the tar.gz file

```
root@akhil-virtual-machine:/home/akhil/Downloads# gtar -xzf OpenSpliceDDSV6.4.140407OSS-HDE-x86.linux-gcc4.6-glibc2.15-installer.tar.gz
No command 'gtar' found, did you mean:
Command 'gjar' from package 'gcj-jdk' (main) 
Command 'ptar' from package 'perl' (main)
Command 'ftar' from package 'fai-client' (universe)
Command 'tar' from package 'tar' (main)
gtar: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in a docker container. I just linked tar to gtar:

```
ln -s /bin/tar /bin/gtar
```

Answer (score 1):

`gtar` is not a command.
Try:

```
tar -zxvf <your_file>.tar.gz
```

Where,

- z : Uncompress the resulting archive with gzip command.
- x : Extract to disk from the archive.
- v : Produce verbose output i.e. show progress and file names while extracting files.
- f data.tar.gz : Read the archive from the specified file called data.tar.gz.

Read `man tar` for more help.

Comment: root@akhil-virtual-machine:/home/akhil/Downloads# ls

etherlab-2.1.0  HDE  HDE_arm  OpenSpliceDDSV6.4.140407OSS-HDE-x86.linux-gcc4.6-glibc2.15-installer.tar.gz  pdcom-3.0.7

root@akhil-virtual-machine:/home/akhil/Downloads# tar -xfvz OpenSpliceDDSV6.4.140407OSS-HDE-x86.linux-gcc4.6-glibc2.15-installer.tar.gz
tar: vz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @AkhilChandraMaganti, i have edit my answer, try: tar -zxvf <your_file>.tar.gz